# Is it possible to use NServiceBus with visual studio express or sharp develop?

Tags: nservicebus, visual-studio-express, sharpdevelop

Is it possible to use NServiceBus with visual studio express or sharp develop?

I want to evaluate the product, and prefer to work on a free development environment.

A partial solution is also relevant.

EDIT

The documentation is based on the visual studio plugin that's incompatible with VS express. Is there documentation regarding developing services without the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NSB does not require any special tooling.